# mPDF generating blank PDF with PHP 7.0.32

Tags: php, pdf-generation, mpdf, php-7.0

I have searched a lot on Google and did not find solution.

mPDF is generating blank PDF on PHP 7.0.32.

Also, no Fatal Error is logged in log files.

Its working with PHP-5.6.10

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
require_once '/src/MPDF/autoload.inc.php';
use \MPDF\Mpdf;
$mpdf = new \Mpdf();
$mpdf->keep_table_proportions = false;
$mpdf->SetTitle($webform->get('title'));
$mpdf->SetDefaultFontSize(9);
$mpdf->SetDefaultFont('"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","DejaVu Sans","Lucida Sans",sans-serif');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>str</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Comment: Show us your code. so that we can help you out!

Comment: Code added, please check now.

Comment: What is your mPDF version? I do not remember version that'd been shipped with autoload.inc.php file. With PHP7 I strongly recommend using mPDF 7+ with composer. Also, your code example smells - you are importing `\MPDF\Mpdf`, but correct case for v7+ is `\Mpdf\Mpdf`, yet you instantiate `new \Mpdf();` which hints mPDF <= 6…

Comment: Please try to rid off `$mpdf->keep_table_proportions = false;` and `$mpdf->SetDefaultFont` (just for testing if it works)

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining `$mdpf` variable here. instead of initializing like this

```
use \MPDF\Mpdf;
```

You have to assign $mpdf variable like

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

So that variable can work accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is was just a segment of code. It was defined. No Fatal Error is generated.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get you. is that was a problem or not.

Comment: No, that was not a problem. The class was instantiated correctly.